# PowerBI - show last value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have some data about company headcount and I want to see in my donut chart only values from this month. I can do it by visual filters, but it isn't dynamic.

I have created measure as follows:

```
Zatrudnienie aktualne = 
CALCULATE([Zatrudnienie],
    FILTER(Kalendarz,MAX(Kalendarz[Date])))
```

Where [Zatrudnienie] is my headcount, but this measure sum all headcount from all months - it is incorrect, I want to see a maximum of my dates - this month as the maximum value.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter condition looks a bit strange with just the MAX.

Try it like this:

```
Zatrudnienie aktualne =
CALCULATE (
    [Zatrudnienie],
    FILTER ( Kalendarz, Kalendarz[Date] = MAX ( Kalendarz[Date] ) )
)
```